# Should the "anime-identification" tag be modified so that it applies to manga as well?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, identification-questions

There's an [anime-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-identification) tag but no corresponding one for identifying manga. It does seem, to me at least, that manga identification requests are significantly rarer than ones for anime, but I do regularly see requests for identification from an image of a panel or a page from a manga (on other anime/manga related sites). Should there be a separate tag for manga identification or should there be a single tag which covers identification of anime, manga, light novels, or whatever else? Also, it seems one of the [questions that's using this tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/what-is-the-song-played-in-cool-device-11-fallen-angel-rina) is requesting an identification of a song, and not of an anime, which leads me to think a more general "identification" type of tag would work better.

Comment: +1 [Tag:Identification] would be better and isn't too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have decided to go with [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request):

- It applies to everything: not just Anime and Manga.
- The "request" makes it very clear that it is a request.

[anime-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-identification) was retagged to it, and synonymed to it.

Comment: As per chat discussion here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7944915#7944915

Answer (score 2):

I would vote *against* [identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification), because it's exactly too broad. This way, it can be used to identify **anything**:

- anime/manga by description
- anime/manga by screenshot
- music
- characters
- places (e.g. "what place was a prototype for the setting of anime X?")
- *anything within the anime/manga*, here are just a couple of random examples I can think of:

  - What brand of T-shirts did character X use in manga Y?
  - What is this food character X is eating in anime Y?
  - ...and so on.

I would vote for having both [anime-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-identification) and [manga-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-identification).

Comment: Would music and characters also have their own tags? The question I linked to uses the [tag:anime-identification] for an ID of music, and [here's a question asking for an ID of a character](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/791/91).