# What *exactly* does [identification-request] cover?

Tags: discussion, tags, identification-questions

We have the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag, clearly for identification requests.

> Questions which ask for help in identifying an anime, manga, or character by description, specific elements (like a character or song), or with screenshots should be tagged with this tag.
>
> This tag should **not** be used for a group of animes (Example: *"What animes have red-haired characters?"*). Such questions are too broad and are not wanted on anime.SE.
>
> — [[identification-request] tag wiki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info)

It seems pretty clear that it should be only for identifying a particular series (anime or manga, though I'd argue light novels, visual novels, and any series in scope can go here too). However, I've seen this tag used on music requests, including [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3639/274), and was edited into [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3106/274) as well. It's also been incorrectly added to questions about identifying components of a series.

What types of identifications fall under this tag, and how should we define it? Also: should we broaden it, or leave it as-is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We had this problem here [Should the "anime-identification" tag be modified so that it applies to manga as well?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/327/27). The tag was originally known as [anime-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-identification), and we've retagged it to become [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request).

My opinion is that [identification-requestion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-requestion) should cover anything the site covers. Be it music from anime, or characters from manga.

We don't need to be strict about this.